# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^n$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\text{Does }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^n \text{ converge?}$$

Using the ratio test we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\bigg(1-(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\bigg)^{n+1}}{\left(1-n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^n}$$ which is pretty ugly.

Comment: Note that the root test is stronger than the ratio test: If the 
ratio test gives you the answer, so does the root test, but not vice versa. In practice, if you see the term is a power of n, you should try using the ratio test first over the root test as well. 

https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0025570x33450.di021200.02p0190s.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} [(1 - n^{1/n})^n]^{1/n} = \lim_{n\to \infty}(1 - n^{1/n}) = 0 < 1,$$

by the root test, your series converges.